# Как прервать выполнение программы после выполнения условия

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно прервать выполнение программы после выполнения условия if

```
a = int(input("Введите первое число" + '\n'))
if a > 2000000000 :
    print("Число слишком велико")
b = int(input("Введите второе число" + '\n'))
if a > 2000000000 :
    print("Число слишком велико")   

evensum = 0
notevensum = 0

for number in range(a, b + 1):
    if number % 2 == 0 :
        evensum += number
    if number % 2 != 0 :
        notevensum +=number

print("Разность суммы четных и суммы нечетных чисел: ", evensum - notevensum)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартный способ завершения программы в Python:

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

или функция `quit()`

```
import sys

a = int(input("Введите первое число" + '\n'))
if a > 2000000000 :
    print("Число слишком велико")
#    sys.exit()
# или так
    quit()

b = int(input("Введите второе число" + '\n'))
#if a > 2000000000 :
if b > 2000000000 :                                # b  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    print("Число слишком велико") 
    sys.exit()    

evensum = 0
notevensum = 0

for number in range(a, b + 1):
    if number % 2 == 0 :
        evensum += number
    if number % 2 != 0 :
        notevensum +=number

print("Разность суммы четных и суммы нечетных чисел: ", evensum - notevensum)
```